# How to add cookies from one domain to other in the domain folder

Tags: javascript, cookies

Recently I deployed my Nest JS backend on domain: name.herokuapp.com and Next JS frontend on domain: name.vercel.app. In both cases names are equal.
Backend set cookies successfully, but in different cookie folder - name.herokuapp.com. But I want that this cookies are located in folder name.vercel.app, so i can attach them in my getServerSideProps function.
My backend code:

```js
res.cookie('accessToken', at, {
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: false,
        path: '/',
});
```

[Result, what i got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMkfL.jpg)

I want, that all cookies are located in name.vercel.app folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there is an answer. This is impossible. That's it.
But you can solve this issue this way:

1. Deploy you front on domain.com;
2. Deploy your backend on any other domain2.com;
3. Connect your domain2.com to api.domain.com or other subdomain using CNAME for example;
4. Send cookies to .(<- **important**)domain.com;

Before I used Vercel to deploy my frontend and Heroku to deploy my backend.
Now I am using [render.com](https://render.com) for back.

Hope, this helps)